# Additional attribute for menu link

Tags: 8, theming, navigation

How I can add `itemprop="url"` for each link (`<a>`) in main menu?

So, I need to get from

```
<a href="/node/114" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/114">Test</a>
```

to

```
<a href="/node/114" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/114" itemprop="url">Test</a>
```

Is it possible to do it in preprocess? I would like not to use any module for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

function HOOK_link_alter(&$variables) or function HOOK_preprocess_menu(&$variables)

Or just override the menu template (`menu--main.html.twig`) and replace line

`{{ link(item.title, item.url, {'class': link_classes}) }}`

with

`{{ link(item.title, item.url, item.attributes.addClass(link_classes).setAttribute('itemprop', 'url') }}`